# In Rails I'm getting this error from Guard saying I have to update to the new :cmd syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, guard

I just updated my gems and when I tried to run Guard, I get the following error :

```
Guard::RSpec DEPRECATION WARNING: The :cli option is deprecated. Please customize the new :cmd option to fit your need.
```

Here's my Guard file:

```
guard 'rspec', cli: '--drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Custom specs
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
    ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
     "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
     (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                       "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
    (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                      "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/sessions_controller\.rb$}) do |m|
    "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"
  end

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end


guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end
```

So how can I use :cmd command to replace '--drb' do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `cmd` option is documented in the `guard-rspec` [README](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#options). Prefix whatever options you had in your `cli:` value with your preferred method of calling `rspec`.

For example, I use Zeus, so I had `zeus: true` and `bundler: false` options in addition to my `cli:` option (all three of which are now deprecated):

```
guard 'rspec', cli: '--color --format nested --fail-fast', zeus: true, bundler: false, all_after_pass: true do
  ...
end
```

If I'm calling Rspec manually outside of guard, I'd use the command line:

```
zeus rspec [spec/]
```

So in my Guardfile, I remove the deprecated options and now use:

```
guard 'rspec', cmd: 'zeus rspec --color --format nested --fail-fast', all_after_pass: true do
  ...
end
```